# How to get current offset of any timezone in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz, datetimeoffset

I need to get the current offset on any timezone in Python. At the moment I am using the `pytz` library and I am getting the offset with this code:

```
import datetime
import pytz
timezone = 'America/Punta_Arenas'
datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(timezone)).utcoffset().total_seconds()/60/60
//prints -3
timezone = 'America/Santiago'
datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(timezone)).utcoffset().total_seconds()/60/60
//prints -4
```

Taking as example 'America/Santiago': this year (2018), DST was set the 13 of May, while in 2015 DST was observed the whole year and in 2014 was set the 27 of April. So, sepending on the date and the year the offset is '-3' or '-4'.

I assume the previous code is not aware of the political decisions of each country regarding DST and probably gets you the offset according to fixed DST dates or something like that. Since I do not know how the nuts and bolts of `datetime` and `pytz` I'd rather ask, is this assumption right?

If it is not aware, how can I get the real current offset for any timezone?

Comment: Not so much: https://www.iana.org/time-zones

Comment: @StephenRauch what do you mean not so much? "not so much" regarding the awareness of the stated code?

Comment: Did you read the link?

Comment: @StephenRauch yes, it is a downloadable database. I am looking more for an API sort of system.

Comment: pytz uses that database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume the previous code is not aware of the political decisions of each country regarding DST and probably gets you the offset according to fixed DST dates or something like that.

Your assumption is incorrect.  Political changes of time zones are recorded and distributed via the [TZ Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).  Those changes are then implemented in hundreds of different libraries, platforms, and operating systems - such as the pytz library you mention.

The change to `America/Santiago` that you describe was reflected in [TZDB 2016c](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2016-March/000037.html), which is implemented in [pytz 2016.3](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/#history).  If you are using pytz 2016.3 or greater, then your code is aware of this change.

Pytz is fine, but you may want to consider using [dateutil](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io) instead.  [Version 2.5.2](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#version-2-5-2) or higher has this data.

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer, @Matt Johnson. Either if I use PyTZ or dateutil I will have to update them if the TZ Database changes (e.g.: a country decides it is not going to implement some DST change), am I right?

Comment: Indeed.  Time zone changes are irregular and unpredictable.  Staying on top of updates is essential.  See also: https://codeofmatt.com/2016/04/23/on-the-timing-of-time-zone-changes/  Specifically the section towards the bottom titled "Recommendations to Software Developers".